# var vs let in node (Module Scope)

Tags: javascript, node.js

In browser javascript, when a variable is declared with `var`, it is appended to the window object, which may cause overriding if another variable with the same name declared with `var` is used by the same or other file in the window. That's why some people say that "var variables are global" and should be avoided:

```js
//Browser JS
var my_var = 3
let my_let = 3

console.log("window.my_var = " + window.my_var)
console.log("window.my_let = " + window.my_let)
```

returns

```
3
undefined
```

As expected.

Similarly, node has the `global` object. I knew  `var` declared variables wouldn't be appended to `global` since node works with module. However, it seems that `var` declared variables are not appended to `module` object:

```js
//Node JS
var my_var = 3
let my_let = 3

console.log("module.my_var = " + module.my_var)
console.log("module.my_let = " + module.my_let)
```

returns

```
module.my_var = undefined
module.my_let = undefined
```

Why is `my_var` not appended to `module`? Does it have module scope? Is it appended elsewhere? What's the difference between var and let in node?

Comment: Node modules run in their own function, so they don't get put onto the global object. The benefits of `const` (and, if you really have to, `let` ) are that they have more intuitive block scope and a DMZ.

Comment: Please open my question again. The linked question does not answer what i asked. I already knew vars would have the module scope, which is answered by the link you posted, i want to know why it's not appended to the module object.

Comment: It's because variables declared in a function *never* get assigned as properties of that function (unless you do so explicitly, like `module.my_var = 'foo'`, which is pretty weird)

Comment: But browsers do that with the ```window``` object...

Comment: No they don't - the window object is not a function all code executes inside of. The window object is just a (non-function) object.

Comment: The thing referred to by `module` is just a plain object. It's not a "scope" where declared variables are put in.